# how to change json data using onclick()?

Tags: angularjs, json

This is a angularjs app.Here I have 2 json files malayalam.js and english.js. when I open the app I want to see application and its data which is comes from malayalam.js(default). and when I click the onclick() in index.html I want to change the content to english.js

app.js

```
$scope.templeMl = 'js/malayalam.js';
$scope.templeEn= 'js/english.js';


 $scope.loadlanguage= function (file) {
        $http.get(file)
        .then(function (result) {
            $scope.result=result;
            console.log($scope.result.data.root);



        })
     }

 $scope.loadLanguages=function(files){
 if(files==english){
$scope.loadlanguage($scope.templeEn);
}
else
{
$scope.loadlanguage($scope.templeml);
}
}
```

index.html

```
<button class="button button-icon" ng-click="loadLanguages(english)">
            en
</button>
```